# Camera picture is left rotated when I take a picture in a physical Android device in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm coding to take a picture in real time and changing it to byte array. The code below works perfectly fine when I use an Android Emulator and take a picture. So when I take a picture through the emulator, the picture is displayed the way I took. But when I connect the project to my physical Android device, when I take a picture, the picture is displayed rotated left 90 degrees. This is what I have for taking a picture.

```
private async void ChangePic(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Change Picture", "Cancel", null, "Take Photo", "Choose from Library");

            if (action == "Take Photo")
            {
                var options = new MediaPickerOptions
                {
                    Title = "Take Photo"
                };

                var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(options);

                if (photo != null)
                {
                    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                        profPicture = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }

                    pictureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(profPicture));
                }
            }
            else if (action == "Choose from Library")
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

I converted the picture into byte array and assigned it as `pictureImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(profPicture));`. In the XAML code I have an image that is named pictureImage, so the taken photo will be displayed there.

```
<Image x:Name="pictureImage" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Black" Margin="0,20,0,10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
                </Image.Clip>
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ChangePic" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Taking a photo runs with no issue in both emulator and the physical device. It is just that the emulator displays the photo correctly but the physical device displays the photo left-rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Pretty normal. Is it a jpg picture? Read its exif header. It contains a rotation variable. Rotate your bitmap back according rotation. Especially Samsung devices place pictures rotated. But it is all according the law. The jpeg definition.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use the MediaPicker in Xamarin.Essentials. There is a known issue on GitHub: [[Bug] MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync - Orientation of photo rotated 90 degrees](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514). Using MediaPicker to capture the photos lost some exif or other metadata. And from [jfversluis comments](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-1004314212), he gave some suggestions for xamarin forms or maui and seems that they would not be able to fix this for Essentials anymore.

However, the community also shared many workarounds, such as using [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-1553621991) or [implement custom service](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1514#issuecomment-1228721149), you may have a try and follow this thread up.